# How long will a frozen lamb roast stay "good" ?

Tags: freezing, lamb

I have a lamb roast in the freezer ( uncooked) that I put there at Christma, will this still be 
"good"?  thank you, Claudia

Answer (score 0):

It will be *safe* indefinitely at freezer temperatures.

For maximum quality, the frozen shelf life (per [Still Tasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17504)) is about 6-9 months.

You would want the lamb well wrapped, so that freezer burn cannot develop.

---

It appears that at the time this question was put in, your lamb is about 4 months frozen, so it should still have good quality if well wrapped.